# react navigation tab navigator specific tab customization

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I achieve the **style customization of one tab** using TabNavigator from React Navigation?
For example if I want that tabs have different colors, how can I do this? Is it possible?

---

I searched everywhere, inclusive [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/), but I haven't got an answer : (

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for might be this one: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/custom

You could custom you own tab navigator component

```
const MyApp = createNavigator(MyRouter)(MyView);
```

then you should be able to change style for MyView all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add your own component in `tabBarComponent` or add your style in

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
const RouteConfigs = { 
// for example these are your scene 
Home ,
Setting
}
const TabNavigatorConfig = {
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
}
}
```

`createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs, TabNavigatorConfig);`